# OwnCloud on Synology-NAS should use OpenDirectory-Server (LDAP)

Tags: networking, ldap, opendirectory

I got a little problem:

I want to configure LDAP with OwnCloud. The LDAP-Service is my OS X Open Directory-Server. OwnCloud runs on Synology DS214play.

Well, I got the domain bureau.example.com which points to my external ip. This IP is static but external connections are blocked. To solve this my OS X server creates a DNS which has a primary zone of bureau.example.com which points to `192.168.10.10` .

On the NAS nslookup for `bureau.example.com` returns `192.168.10.10` so I should be able to use `bureau.example.com` as LDAP-server in own cloud.

But this does not work. It only works if I use `192.168.10.10` as LDAP-host. Any ideas regarding this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your OS X Server and the openCloud version! How exactly do you you `dig` or `nslookup` the dns name of bureau.example.com?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-)OwnCloud: ownCloud 8.0.2 (stable)
OS X Server.app: 4.1.3

I used ssh to login to NAS and used `nslookup bureau.example.com` and got back 192.168.10.10 .

Comment: And what are your 1st and 2nd DNS-server in SynologyDSM -> Control Panel -> Network -> General?

Comment: Hi klanomath, first is 192.168.10.10 and second is 8.8.8.8 .